# touchesBegan location issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitouch

I am updating some old code and I have a subclassed UIView (GraphView) that has the following touchesBegan code:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
if ([self.grapher.gLayers pointInside:point]) {
NSLog(@"gLayer has point");
... do some stuff
}

// Draw a red dot where the touch occurred
UIView *touchView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[touchView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
touchView.frame = CGRectMake(point.x-5, point.y-5, 10, 10);
touchView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
[self addSubview:touchView];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[touchView setAlpha:0.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[touchView release];  
}
```

I'd like to move this code (which works fine in GraphView.m) into the GraphViewController.m for this view but I'm getting 2 errors. The first is that

```
self.grapher.gLayers
```

generates an error saying the 'Property grapher not found on object of type UIView.' How would I write this properly in the viewcontroller? I'm currently using

```
self.view.grapher.gLayers
```

The second error I'm getting is on the line

```
touchView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
```

The error says 'Property 'cornerRadius' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer *''. Why would this code work in the UIView but not the viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is grapher a property of your view?

Did you import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`?

**Edit**

OK.  You're moving this from GraphView *to* GraphViewController?  Does GraphViewController use a xib?  You'll need to change the class of view from UIView to GraphView.  With IB, select the View and then change the Custom Class to GraphView.

Comment: Yes grapher is a property of the view.  Importing QuartzCore fixed the second issue

Comment: Your view controller need to have a custom UIView called GraphView.  See my edit above.